{ggplot2} can not render .pdf file format when using {marquee}
I am using {ggplot} and {marquee} to render a plot. I tried to save the plot in .pdf format but somehow the file I got is broken.
For example, this is what I get when I open it on a Windows machine using Adobe Reader:
[
I tried to:

open the file on an Android device: 
render the plot in .png which works as I expected:


So, the question is: how do I render ggplot+marquee in .pdf?
FYI this is my code:
range_max_dum <- 0.015
point_size <- 3
gray_line_size <- point_size - .75
max_color <- "#176b87"
min_color <- "#ffab40"

dum_legend <- glue::glue(
"Pooled effect sizes from {.[max_color] **all the included studies**} and {.[min_color] **when outliers and < median samle sizes removed**}", 
.open = "[",
.close = "]")

dum_plot_data <- 
    tibble::tribble(
        ~country,       ~es.x,       ~ul.x,       ~ll.x,       ~es.y,       ~ul.y,       ~ll.y,     ~min_es,
        "China", 0.035799021, 0.044116242,  0.02832098, 0.023210599, 0.029256901, 0.017848775, 0.017848775,
        "United Kingdom", 0.011771449, 0.032197434, 0.001366486, 0.004588374, 0.008391918, 0.001920112, 0.001366486,
        "United Arab Emirates", 0.010544074, 0.013057569, 0.008294895, 0.010544074, 0.013057569, 0.008294895, 0.008294895,
        "India", 0.050080298,  0.07488636, 0.030041038, 0.019575116, 0.037859183, 0.007191735, 0.007191735,
        "Saudi Arabia", 0.003460838, 0.004283512, 0.002725023, 0.003460838, 0.004283512, 0.002725023, 0.002725023,
        "Canada", 0.024949252, 0.038100772,  0.01451395, 0.011457303,  0.01343168, 0.009637608, 0.009637608
    )
  
dum_plot_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = country)) +
  
  geom_linerange(
    aes(xmin = es.y, xmax = es.x), 
    color = "gray65", 
    linewidth = gray_line_size,
    alpha = .32) +
  
  geom_linerange(
    xmin = -.05, 
    aes(xmax = min_es), 
    color = "gray10", 
    linetype = 5,
    linewidth = .35,
    alpha = .45) +
  
  geom_point(
    aes(x = es.y), 
    color = min_color, 
    size = point_size) +
  
  geom_linerange(
    aes(xmin = ll.y, xmax = ul.y),
    color = min_color,
    alpha = .5) +
  
  geom_point(
    aes(x = es.x), 
    color = max_color, 
    size = point_size) + 
  
  geom_linerange(
    aes(xmin = ll.x, xmax = ul.x),
    color = max_color,
    alpha = .5) +
  
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(0, range_max_dum), labels = scales::label_percent(), 
    breaks = seq(0, range_max_dum, by = .05)) + 
  
  labs(
    x = "Incidence",
    title = dum_legend) +
  
  theme_minimal() +
  
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(), 
    axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12.5),
    axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 10), 
    plot.title = element_marquee(width = 1))

ggsave(
  filename = "test.pdf", 
  device = "pdf",
  width  =  20,
  height =  30,
  units  = "cm")

Session Info:
sessionInfo()

R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

time zone: Asia/Tehran
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices
[4] utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] marquee_0.1.0                
 [2] ggtext_0.1.2                 
 [3] glue_1.7.0                   
 [4] ggforce_0.5.0                
 [5] showtext_0.9-6               
 [6] showtextdb_3.0               
 [7] sysfonts_0.8.8               
 [8] sf_1.0-16                    
 [9] rnaturalearthhires_1.0.0.9000
[10] rnaturalearthdata_1.0.0      
[11] rnaturalearth_1.0.1          
[12] furrr_0.3.1.9000             
[13] future_1.34.0                
[14] magick_2.8.3                 
[15] officer_0.6.7                
[16] flextable_0.9.7              
[17] broom_1.0.6                  
[18] metafor_4.6-0                
[19] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1          
[20] metadat_1.2-0                
[21] Matrix_1.6-5                 
[22] janitor_2.2.0                
[23] lubridate_1.9.3              
[24] forcats_1.0.0                
[25] stringr_1.5.1                
[26] dplyr_1.1.4                  
[27] purrr_1.0.2                  
[28] readr_2.1.5                  
[29] tidyr_1.3.1                  
[30] tibble_3.2.1                 
[31] ggplot2_3.5.1                
[32] tidyverse_2.0.0              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] DBI_1.2.1              
 [2] readxl_1.4.3           
 [3] rlang_1.1.4            
 [4] magrittr_2.0.3         
 [5] snakecase_0.11.1       
 [6] e1071_1.7-14           
 [7] compiler_4.3.3         
 [8] systemfonts_1.1.0      
 [9] vctrs_0.6.5            
[10] pkgconfig_2.0.3        
[11] crayon_1.5.3           
[12] fastmap_1.2.0          
[13] backports_1.4.1        
[14] labeling_0.4.3         
[15] utf8_1.2.4             
[16] rmarkdown_2.29         
[17] tzdb_0.4.0             
[18] camcorder_0.1.0        
[19] ragg_1.3.3             
[20] xfun_0.49              
[21] jsonlite_1.8.9         
[22] tweenr_2.0.2           
[23] uuid_1.2-1             
[24] terra_1.7-71           
[25] parallel_4.3.3         
[26] R6_2.5.1               
[27] stringi_1.8.3          
[28] parallelly_1.39.0      
[29] car_3.1-2              
[30] cellranger_1.1.0       
[31] Rcpp_1.0.13-1          
[32] knitr_1.49             
[33] timechange_0.3.0       
[34] tidyselect_1.2.1       
[35] rstudioapi_0.16.0      
[36] abind_1.4-8            
[37] codetools_0.2-19       
[38] listenv_0.9.1          
[39] lattice_0.22-5         
[40] withr_3.0.2            
[41] askpass_1.2.1          
[42] evaluate_1.0.1         
[43] units_0.8-5            
[44] proxy_0.4-27           
[45] polyclip_1.10-6        
[46] zip_2.3.1              
[47] xml2_1.3.6             
[48] pillar_1.9.0           
[49] carData_3.0-5          
[50] KernSmooth_2.23-22     
[51] generics_0.1.3         
[52] rprojroot_2.0.4        
[53] mathjaxr_1.6-0         
[54] hms_1.1.3              
[55] munsell_0.5.1          
[56] scales_1.3.0           
[57] globals_0.16.3         
[58] class_7.3-22           
[59] gdtools_0.4.1          
[60] tools_4.3.3            
[61] data.table_1.16.2      
[62] grid_4.3.3             
[63] colorspace_2.1-1       
[64] nlme_3.1-164           
[65] cli_3.6.3              
[66] textshaping_0.4.0      
[67] rsvg_2.6.0             
[68] fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1
[69] fansi_1.0.6            
[70] svglite_2.1.3          
[71] gtable_0.3.6           
[72] rstatix_0.7.2          
[73] digest_0.6.36          
[74] fontquiver_0.2.1       
[75] classInt_0.4-10        
[76] gifski_1.12.0-2        
[77] farver_2.1.2           
[78] htmltools_0.5.8.1      
[79] lifecycle_1.0.4        
[80] here_1.0.1             
[81] httr_1.4.7             
[82] gridtext_0.1.5         
[83] fontLiberation_0.1.0   
[84] openssl_2.2.2          
[85] MASS_7.3-60.0.1        


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

Sure. I added a sham data to the code.

Hm. This looks like an issue related to Windows. I have no issues when running the code on my Mac, but can reproduce on Windows. Looks like a font issue.

Thank you, Stefan! I'll post it as an issue on GitHub then.

For those interested in following the issue, here is a link to the issue on GitHub.
